# Validar que un campo tenga obligatoriamente dobles comillas

Tags: javascript, regex

Buenas quiero una validación tipo pattern (atributo html) para validar que lo que hay en el campo tenga dobles comillas en el campo se puede tambien añadir espacios. Algo así.

campo a introducir : `pepe el tuerto`->malo

campo a introducir : `"pepe el tuerto"` ->correcto

Se os ocurre algo?

Comment: ¿Y has probado algo? Si pones en el campo pattern una regex tipo `^\".+\"$` debería funcionar, no?

Comment: `let text = '<span data-info="pepe el tuerto" >'`
`let rex = /\"[\w\s]+\"/g`
`console.log(text.match(rex))`

Comment: He agregado la etiqueta `regex`, por si algún experto en la materia puede darte la mejor forma de hacer esto.

Comment: si ya usas javascript porque tan solo no lo conviertes x javascript..algo asi: var cadena = $("#id_input").val();
  var cadena_valida = "'"+ cadena + "'";

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908971/adding-double-quotes-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres usar la validación tipo `pattern` de `HTML` puedes usar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
\x22[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\x22$
```

Donde:

`\x22`: indica que el texto ha de empezar con comilla doble `"`.

`[A-Za-z0-9 ]+`: indica que acepta cualquier letra del alfabeto (mayúscula y/o minúscula), números del 0 al 9 y espacios, y el `+` indica que pueden repetirse.

'\x22$': indica que el texto ha de finalizar con comilla doble `"`.

Un ejemplo de uso en `HTML`:

```js
function alertMessage() {
  if(!document.getElementById("text").value) {
    window.alert('Input vacío');
  } else {
    window.alert('El input es válido');
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="alertMessage();">
  <input type="text" id="text" pattern="\x22[A-Za-z0-9 ]+\x22$">
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Sin embargo debes tener en cuenta la versión del navegador, ya que navegadores muy antiguos pueden tener problemas con la expresión regular.

Otra cosa es el hecho de que un `input` vacío pasa el control del pattern, por eso puse un `if else` en la función `alertMessage()`.

O puedes usar la etiqueta `required` en el `input`. Ya es cuestión de la lógica de tu programa.

Saludos.